# Nested routing in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, nested-sets

My model class is:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_nested_set
  has_many :children, :foreign_key => "parent_id", :class_name => 'Category'
  belongs_to :parent, :foreign_key => "parent_id", :class_name => 'Category' 


  def to_param
    slug
  end
end
```

Is it possible to have such recursive route like this:
`/root_category_slug/child_category_slug/child_of_a_child_category_slug` ... and so one

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with regular routes and [Route Globbing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing), so for example,

```
map.connect 'categories/*slugs', :controller => 'categories', :action => 'show_deeply_nested_category'
```

Then in your controller

```
def show_deeply_nested_category
  do_something = params[:slugs]  # contains an array of the path segments
end
```

However, note that [nested resource routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting) more than one level deep isn't recommended.

Comment: I had the same question, and this works perfectly.  I would argue Jamis' rule doesn't apply in this case, since the resource itself is represented as a hierarchical structure.  (And there's no need to use nested resources/routes in this case anyway).

Comment: I had to use 'match' instead of 'map.connect' and it worked perfectly

Comment: What should be done as an alternative to nesting more than one deep?  The documentation doesn't say.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it, and it's not a good idea.  Rails Route mapping code is complex enough without having to dynamically try to encode & decode (possibly) infinite route strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use constraints in rails routing. eg:

```
match '*id', :to => 'categories#show', :constraints => TaxonConstraint.new

class TaxonConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    path = request.path.slice(1..(request.path.length-1)
    path = path.split('/')
    return false if path.length != path.uniq.length
    return true if Category.check(path.last).first
    false
  end
end
```

class splits your path by "/" , and checks db for last element in db. if not found, skips the route.
if any one knows, how to solve it better, would be glad to hear.

Comment: heh, i found best solution. then create new category with acts_as_nested_set, you can generate path to root in 1 query. and then just check field "path" => "a/b/c".

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy (read: I don't know how to do it) and it's not advised. Imagine if you have 10 categories, you do not want the url to be `/categorya/categoryb/categoryc/categoryd/categorye/categoryf/categoryg/categoryh/categoryi/categoryj`.

Perhaps a maximum level of 3 would grant you the power you desire, without polluting the URL?

Comment: For my opinion level the level should be limited by the model, not by the routing rule.

Comment: @Ryan Bigg, how would you prefer to write a URL for something like this, assuming you do have n-depth? he's trying to show a category in a certain location in the tree (and it could have others).